# For JSON results

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Sorry for the basic of this question, I just cannot wrap my head around this one.

I need the output from SQL Server to look like this.

In a little more human readable format:

```
var data = [
  {
    name: '2017', id: -1,
    children: [
      { name: '01-2017', id: 11 },
      { name: '02-2017', id: 12 },
      { name: '03-2017', id: 13 },
      { name: '04-2017', id: 14 },
      { name: '05-2017', id: 15 },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '2018', id: -1,
    children: [
      { name: '01-2018', id: 6 },
      { name: '02-2018', id: 7 },
      { name: '03-2018', id: 8 },
      { name: '04-2018', id: 9 },
      { name: '05-2018', id: 10 },
    ]
  }
];
```

This is a snapshot of the data:

[image]

The group I will be working with is `userid = 1`.

My first thought was to use a cursor to loop through all the distinct reportYear for `userid = 1`, then a `select` based on the year and the userid to fill in the sub-query.

There has to be a way without using a cursor.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? And if you want JSON returned why do you need it be human legible?

Comment: sql server = azure

Comment: the human readable part is to simply make it a little easier to read

Comment: I sort of assumed that but once you are past debugging it shouldn't matter really right? I would suggest you use the JSON functions and not do this manually. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Your link is nice, thank you.   But not what i am looking for...   i am looking for help in <b>building the query</b> to return the results that are shown in the 'human readable' section of the question.  I know the data works that is hard coded in the string, but i need help in creating the query to return the results to match the hard coded data, using the screen snap as the source of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output joining your table to a query that  extracts all the years to be used at the top level elements and then generating the json using `FOR JSON AUTO`:

```
declare @tmp table (monthlyReportID int, userID int, reportMonth int, reportYear int)
insert into @tmp values
( 6, 1, 1, 2018),
( 7, 1, 2, 2018),
( 8, 1, 3, 2018),
( 9, 1, 4, 2018),
(10, 1, 5, 2018),
(11, 1, 1, 2017),
(12, 1, 2, 2017),
(13, 1, 3, 2017),
(14, 1, 4, 2017),
(15, 1, 5, 2017)

select years.[name], children.[name], children.[id] from 
(
    select distinct reportYear as [name] from  @tmp
) as years 
left join
(
    select monthlyReportID as [id]
    ,right('0' + cast(reportMonth as varchar(2)),2) + '-' + cast(reportYear as varchar(4)) as [name]
    ,reportYear as [year]
    from  @tmp 
) as children
on children.[Year] = years.[name]
for json auto
```

I omitted the `ID` field because in your desired output it is always set to **-1** and I was not able to understand the logic behind it.

Nonetheless you should be able to easily edit the script above to obtain the value you need.

Here are the results:

```js
[
  {
    "name": 2017,
    "children": [
      {"name": "01-2017", "id": 11},
      {"name": "02-2017", "id": 12},
      {"name": "03-2017", "id": 13},
      {"name": "04-2017", "id": 14},
      {"name": "05-2017", "id": 15}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": 2018,
    "children": [
      {"name": "01-2018", "id": 6},
      {"name": "02-2018", "id": 7},
      {"name": "03-2018", "id": 8},
      {"name": "04-2018", "id": 9},
      {"name": "05-2018", "id": 10}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This was PERFECT!!  Many thanks!   (i.e. the -1 on the name/year node was because the tree controller event click fires on every click on the tree, and i check for the values before doing anything, so if it a negative one, then i do not do anything)  kinda cheesy, but the tree control is being forced on me.